# Probability of a data point being well classified

Tags: python, sklearn-pandas, unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning

I have a mix of labeled and unlabeled data, this last one I would like to classify it by using semi-supervised learning. Suppose I have already an algorithm that gives me the best accuracy at predicting the labels of the training subsample. I want to use that algorithm to predict the labels of the unlabeled subsample. In semi-supervised learning, the pseudo-labeled data is added to the labeled (training) one. I would like to select from the pseudo-labeled data only those points that the probability of being well classified is higher than, let's say, 0.8, and repeat the procedure till all the unlabeled data is pseudo-labeled with high probability.
How could I achieve this? Is there a code or built-in function that helps me to compute such a probability?

Answer (score 0):

All these algorithms

AdaBoostClassifier, BaggingClassifier, BayesianGaussianMixture, BernoulliNB, CalibratedClassifierCV, ComplementNB, DecisionTreeClassifier, ExtraTreeClassifier, ExtraTreesClassifier, GaussianMixture, GaussianNB, GaussianProcessClassifier,
GradientBoostingClassifier, KNeighborsClassifier, LabelPropagation, LabelSpreading, LinearDiscriminantAnalysis, LogisticRegression, LogisticRegressionCV, MLPClassifier, MultinomialNB, NuSVC, QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis, RandomForestClassifier, SGDClassifier, SVC, _BinaryGaussianProcessClassifierLaplace, _ConstantPredictor

support a method called predict_proba(self, X), that doest precisely that.